# Received a strange text message. What is it?

Tags: android, exploit, attacks, ios, sms

This morning I received the following text message from a Gmail account:

`v3s5f3rs4f3gs3.nf5j4k8j4k3o.solar?G$1?V&?KL?O=$HO?&S?K0?$1T`

A couple of my friends got it too.  I have an iPhone and it didn't do anything, but on android phones, it shows up as a link (both were smart enough not to tap it).

What is this message?  I'm guessing it's some attempted SMS hack similar to the infamous iMessage bug a few years back that bricked some peoples' iPhones.  Does anyone have any details?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking to explain arbitrary strange text are off-topic. Just as analysing code, deobfuscating code, or asking to decode/decrypt text,

Comment: As @D M stated, .solar is a TLD and query parameters.
Without query parameters, lets follow the link: 
**v3s5f3rs4f3gs3.nf5j4k8j4k3o.solar** X-Served-By: Namecheap URL Forward to => **campaignsrus.com** Sets cookies sends tracking to Cloudflare =>  **clik.global-trk.com** Sets cookies, no robots, no indexing tags =>  **securepremiums.com** Sets cookies, pulls remote javascript, and creates frame content: **bangahoe.com** bangahoe.com/tours. *Exactly what it seems.*

*Misc tracker and fingerprinting attempts.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.solar` is a [top level domain (TLD)](https://icannwiki.org/.solar) so I checked the [WHOIS](https://lookup.icann.org/lookup) for `nf5j4k8j4k3o.solar`.

> | Property | Value |
> | --- | --- |
> | Name | nf5j4k8j4k3o.solar |
> | Created | 2021-03-19 09:58:10 UTC |
> | Registrar | NameCheap, Inc. |

Your text can be broken up as follows:

```
v3s5f3rs4f3gs3.nf5j4k8j4k3o.solar?G$1?V&?KL?O=$HO?&S?K0?$1T
```

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| v3s5f3rs4f3gs3 | Sub-domain |
| nf5j4k8j4k3o.solar | Domain |
| ?`G$1?V`&`?KL?O=$HO?`&`S?K0?$1T` | Query parameters |

It's definitely a link, and given how garbled it appears and how recently the linked domain was registered, this is unquestionably a phishing attack. The sender is counting on the recipient to click the link.

I'd suggest that you report the domain to the registrar via `abuse@namecheap.com`. The associated domain ID is:

```
a54f6533a1a3416eb6f07a953dee0931-DONUTS
```